# NoReverseMatch using through model

Tags: django

This code in my views.py works fine when it was still not in template format

```
def detail(request, entity_group_id):
    entity_group = get_object_or_404(EntityGroup, pk=entity_group_id) # noqa
    entity_list = entity_group.members.order_by('name')
    context = {
        'entity_group': entity_group,
        'entity_list': entity_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'core/detail.html', context)
```

When I changed it into a Generic View a NoReverseMatch comes up...

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = EntityGroup
    template_name = 'core/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entity_group'] = EntityGroup
        context['entity_list'] = EntityGroup.members
        return context
```

Here is my models.py

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class EntityGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    entity_group = models.ForeignKey(EntityGroup, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
```

How do I set a reverse on the Generic view?

This is the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [
    # # path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # path('<int:entity_group_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # path('<int:entity_group_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # path('<int:entity_group_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:entity_group_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

This is the Traceback requested:

```
File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  88.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\acer-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  632.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /core/2/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['core\\/(?P<entity_group_id>[0-9]+)\\/vote\\/$']
```

I have a vote view which works fine before changing the Detail view in the template that's why I didn't post it here.

Comment: Post your `urls.py` and the traceback please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original view, you were explicitly passing an `EntityGroup` object instance to your template.

```
entity_group = get_object_or_404(EntityGroup, pk=entity_group_id)

context = {
    'entity_group': entity_group
```

But in your new `DetailView` you are passing the `EntityGroup` class, not an object instance.

```
context['entity_group'] = EntityGroup
```

The template may therefore trigger the `NoReverseMatch` when it tries to render a URL based on an id which it cannot lookup.

In your new `DetailView`, try passing the object instance.

```
context['entity_group'] = self.get_object()
```